# Consequence vs Assumption?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

I am just a beginner ESL teacher. I find myself a beginner because I cannot answer the question of my student about what we were discussing at least two days ago.

To give context. We are discussing a business course, and suddenly the student asked me the difference between "consequences" and "assumption" and how does "adverbs" connect with "assumption."

The first thing that came into my mind was, well, consequences always have a negative notion. The student said consequences are not always negative. It is usually the effect of the cause or the result of an action that happened. My student is Spanish, to give additional context.

[image: Lesson screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Assumption adverbs are a type of adverb.  In the example sentence "Naturally" is an assumption adverb. It modifies the sentence to show that it states an assumption.

Consequences and assumptions are quite different.  As a piece of advice, don't think you are not allowed to use a dictionary.  It is good for teachers to model how to use a dictionary to check meanings:

Consequence: a result or effect. (often but not always a negative effect)

(*It wouldn't work* is a consequence of "certain information being lost)

Assumption: a thing that is accepted as true, without proof.

(*It will affect the month end closure* is an assumption. The word "Naturally" states that this is obviously true, but doesn't offer any proof or evidence) Assumptions can be true or false.

> I assumed he could speak Spanish, so I began to talk. But I was wrong! The consequence was that he didn't understand what I said.

Comment: Thank you. This is a useful advice and explanation. I really appreciate it!